# SQL Server Always Encrypted C++

Tags: sql, sql-server, always-encrypted

I am trying to set up Always Encrypted option for my database.

By following the Microsoft link, I was able to do the same and also verify using SSMS.

However, I am facing a problem while using the same feature in my application.

My client application is developed in C++.

When ever I try to retrieve data from the encrypted columns, the values are not in plain text but encrypted.

I tried setting all possible flags in my connection string but nothing seems to work.

Based on this, I have two questions:

1. What is the connection string flag to be used for enabling Always Encrypted in a C++ application that uses OpenEx API to connect to dB?
2. Is it not supported in C++? Most of the samples mention usage of .NET framework 4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlwaysEncrypted requires the client driver to provide the encryption key and to understand the column encryption metadata.

From C/C++ you should use ODBC for AlwaysEncrypted support. See [Using Always Encrypted - ODBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-always-encrypted-with-the-odbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thanks David. Using ODBC driver worked.